# ¿alguien sabe por que salta error?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
try:
    print(1)
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
    except AssertionError:
        print(3)
        except:
            print(4)
```

Me sale el error:

```
    except AssertionError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: por favor indica exactamente qué ejecutas y cómo

Answer (score 4):

Tu error se encuentra en el posicionamiento

Recuerda que en python es muy importante a que nivel se encuentra, por un espacio de mas o faltante te puede arrojar un error.

```
try:
    print(1)
    assert 2 + 2 == 5
except AssertionError:
    print(3)
except:
    print(4)
```

## Y asi arreglas el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]